# Azure transcription is not recognizing anything

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have a button in my UI to start a transcribing process, but for some reason is not working

this is the service file

```
  public List<char> Letters { get; set; }

        public StringBuilder Builder { get; set; }

        public AzureTranscriptionService() {

            Letters = new List<char>();
            Builder = new StringBuilder();

        }
        public async Task<string> ConvertToTextAsync(
            string FilePath,
            string Language,
            string WordDocName) {


            //Configure speech service

            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription
                (ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_KEY,
                ConstantsHelpers.AZURE_REGION);

            config.EnableDictation();

            config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = Language;

            //Configure speech recognition

            var taskCompleteionSource
                = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput
                (FilePath);

            {

                using var speechRecognizer =
                    new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioConfig);

                speechRecognizer.Recognized += (sender, e) => {
                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
                        foreach (var c in e.Result.Text) {
                            Letters.Add(c);

                            Debug.WriteLine(c);
                        }
                    }
                };

                speechRecognizer.SessionStarted += (sender, e) => {

                    Debug.WriteLine("------> Started");
                };

                speechRecognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, e) => {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Stop");

                    foreach (var item in Letters) {
                        Builder.Append(item);
                    }
                };
                speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (sender, e) => {

                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
                };

                await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                Task.WaitAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });

                await speechRecognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return Builder.ToString();
        }
```

I call this service in my main ViewModel, ad the only output I can see is ---> I started

I put this method for debugging, and I don't see anything

```
 speechRecognizer.Recognizing += (sender, e) => {

                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
                };
```

it's is where I called the service

```
private async void StartAction(object obj) {

            var FileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
                (FilePath);

            var AudioPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);

            var DocumentPath = FolderHelper.CreateFolder();

            var AudioFileNamePath = Path.Combine(AudioPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.WAV}");

            var ConvertedAudioPath = AudioHelper.Converter(FilePath!, AudioFileNamePath);

            var DocumentName = Path.Combine(DocumentPath, $"{FileWithoutExtension}{ConstantsHelpers.DOCX}");

            await AzureTranscription.ConvertToTextAsync(ConvertedAudioPath,
                SelectedItem, DocumentName);
        }
```

I cannot figure it out, I am passing everything that is required in order for it to work

Comment: Your `taskCompleteionSource` never completes...

Comment: `Task.WaitAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });` <-- **don't do this**: you're mixing synchronous methods (`WaitAny`) with async methods - not least how `taskCompleteionSource` never completes anyway.

Comment: What would be yo suggestion

Comment: There's a full example of recognizing speech from an audio file on-disk here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognize-speech-from-a-file

Comment: Yes but it doesn't tell you how to continuously recognize

Comment: Your code doesn't show an attempt to continuously recognize from a microphone because you're using `AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput` instead.

Comment: So what is your recommendation

I follow this code https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/dotnet-windows/speechtotext-naudio/speechtotext-naudio/Program.cs

Comment: By the way, I am recognizing from a file, not a microphone @Dai

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously" recognizing speech in a file? Files don't work like that.

Comment: I am trying to recognize all the Wav file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248982/discussion-between-eduardo-gomez-and-dai).